# Sql Query converting to Linq Query By using Wcf Service Platefrom

Tags: c#, linq, wcf

I am currently working on Wcf Service and consuming it in Angular JS application.
I am trying converting Sql query to Linq Query. I am creating user login system based on username and password . If user enter wrong username and password four time then I want locked user account into sql database . Otherwise if user enter wrong username and password first time but enter correct username and password second time then I want to return the method true and recount the Attempt to Zero . But I am getting expected result with the Linq query .

Here is my ADO.NET Code ...

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
    {

        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string encryptedpassword = FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(userLogin.Password, "SHA1");
            SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", userLogin.Username);
            SqlParameter paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", encryptedpassword);

            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);

            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                int RetryAttempts = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RetryAttempts"]);
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["AccountLocked"]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (RetryAttempts > 0)
                {
                    int AttemptsLeft = (4 - RetryAttempts);

                }

                else if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["Authenticated"]))
                {
                    return true;
                }

                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my Linq query I tried to converted but it is not giving expecting result .

```
 public bool AuthenticateUser(UserLogin userLogin)
                {
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities db = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
                    {
      var attamp = from X in db.tblUsers
     where X.Username == userLogin.Username&&  X.Password == userLogin.Password
      select X.RetryAttempts != 4;
      return attamp.Single();

                    }
                }
```

What will the correct Linq for Following Sql query

Comment: May I know what do you want to achieve with LINQ query?

Comment: Because with the ADO.NET I am receiving Null Reference Exception but with Linq Query I am able to run it successful

Comment: Do you want the linq to return whether the limit exceeded or not?

Comment: Yes . I want to return the number of attempt  user made as well

Comment: The maximum limit is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to take out the password from filter to calculate total number of retries. but use it while actually authenticating the user.

Also once it is successfully authenticated reset the counter to zero.

```
bool LimitExceeded()
{
var exceeded=false;
var totalRetries =-1;
var attamp = from X in db.tblUsers
                where X.Username == userLogin.Username 
                select X

 if( attamp.Any())
 {
        if(attamp.firstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.HasValue)      totalRetries =attamp.firstOrDefault().RetryAttempts;
        exceeded=  totalRetries>4;
 }
 return exceeded
}
```

The above code is not written using any code editor. That may not compile.  I just wrote to give you an idea.

Comment: I dont know where you can add it for sure. But what it does is,
1) Calculate the number of retries made already using the user name
2) Gives a boolean to check the allowed 4 retries already consumed or not

Comment: There is an error can not convert to int? to int /.An explicitly conversion is exist ..    totalRetries =attamp.firstOrDefault().RetryAttempts

Comment: What is the datatype of your property "RetryAttempts"?

Comment: int32. RetryAttempts

Comment: Check for null if the field is nullable

Comment: how to do it . RetryAttempts  filed will be null when user enter correct username and password

Comment: If it is nullable int then you can use the RetryAttempts.HasValue. Can you please google on how to check nulls?

Comment: var attamp = from X in db.tblUsers
                             where X.Username == userLogin.Username&& X.Password== userLogin.Password&& X.RetryAttempts!=null
                             select X;

Comment: Change the below code in the limitExeeded function to fix the null check. You dont need to change the LINQ query I haved shared in this answer
if(attamp.firstOrDefault().RetryAttempts.HasValue)  totalRetries =attamp.firstOrDefault().RetryAttempts;

Comment: should I delete this code from query....totalRet‌​ries =attamp.firstOrDefault().RetryAttempts

Comment: please check the answer